# Comparing multiple address machines by writing programs to compute an equation?

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture

Compute zero-, one-, two- and three address machines by writing programs to compute:

```
X = (B - C) / (A * D)
```

For each of the four machines the instructions available for use are follows:

```
0 Address
PUSH 
POP 
ADD
MUL
DIV
SUB

1 Address
LOAD 
STORE 
MUL 
DIV 
SUB

2 Address
MOVE (X, Y)

MUL (X, Y)
DIV (X, Y)
SUB (X, Y)


3 Address


SUB (X, X, Y)
MUL (X, X, Y)
DIV (X, X, Y)
```

---

```
a) Zero-Address ...


b) One-Address ...


c) two-Address ...


d) three--Address ...
```

I will award top answer as soon as I can! All help is appreciated!

Edit: I believe I solved A... I got

```
Push B
Push C
Sub
Push A
Push D
MUL
DIV
Pop X
```

Edit2: I believe I solved B as well, if you see something wrong with my answers let me know please...

```
Load A
MUL D
Store T
Load B
Sub C
Div T 
Store X
```

Comment: Not 100% positive, but I am pretty sure it's points or something like that :) I know for yahoo answers it's +10. I have an account with over 2,000 points on there, but stack is much better for my Computer Science questions.

Answer (score 1):

1) 0-address

It seems that depending on the intended order of the stack registers your ordering might be incorrect. After

> ```
> Push B
> Push C
> Sub
> Push A
> Push D
> MUL
> ```

the stack will contain

> ```
> A*D
> B-C
> ```

Which might divide in reverse order.

2) 1-address.

It seems that it would could be more efficient to do

> ```
> Load B
> Sub C
> Div A
> Div D
> Store X
> ```

Assuming that your memory latency plus multiplies latency is higher than Division latency.
Also assuming that it is allowed to transform

> x = (B - C) / (A * D) into X = ((B - C) / A) / D

3) 2-address

If we assume that we can have 2 temp registers then:

> ```
> MOV B T1
> SUB T1 C
> MOV A T2
> MUL D T2
> DIV T1 T2
> ```

If we assume only one temp register, but allow changing the formula just like in 2, then

> ```
> MOV B T
> SUB T C
> DIV T A
> DIV T D
> ```

IF neither of those are allowed, then:

> ```
> MOV B T
> SUB T C
> MOV C MEM
> MOV A T
> MUL A D
> DIV MEM T
> ```

4) 3-address

> ```
> SUB T1, B, C     # T1 = B - C
> MUL T2, A, D     # T2 = A * D
> DIV T2, T1, T2
> ```